# Can anyone identify this Raleigh bike?

Tags: identify-this-bike

[image]

And whether it's worth buying for $175?

Comment: A few more detailed pictures would help.  The stem shifters suggest prior to about 1985 to me.  I'm suspicious that the handlebar and brake levers been changed.  (Looks like an ROPA, though -- ridden once, put away.)

Comment: (Unless it's somehow a "classic" that would interest a collector (unlikely for a Raleigh) it's not worth $175.)

Comment: The price is very much going to depend on the area you are in. I'm sure I've seen similar bikes in my area asking for a similar price.  I'm not sure if they ever sold for that much, but that seems to be a reasonable start. Definitely try to talk them down a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer** Its a late 80s bike, maybe an early 90s. The frame is a mixte, so probably sold as a woman's bike.  Almost certainly a steel frame.

The brake hoods have sissy bars, which were common in the 80s for those who didn't ride on the hoods and preferred to ride on the tops.

Shifter levers are up on the quill stem, so its more recent than downtube shifters.

The metal dork disk on the back wheel dates it to late 80s as well.  Plastic was more common later.

Can't see a lot of the transmission, but it looks like a 2x5 or a 2x6, which means a freewheel not a freehub.

The mudguards / fenders are not original, and maybe the saddle is a replacement as well.

If you test-ride it, particularly check out the tyres before riding.  Gumwalls like that could easily be 20 years old now, and haven't been commonly sold, so they're a minimum of a decade old.

**DANGERS**  It might be the photo but the left hand handlebar looks odd.  Almost looks like its a sharper curve than the right hand side, which makes me wonder about crash damage.  Inspect it closely.

**Valuation** We don't do valuations here.  You need to compare it to other similar bikes in *your* vicinity and see if its in-line with other local offerings.  Something's value is determined by what one person will pay for it, which is related to scarcity.   Don't just buy it because you like the colour.

Comment: I generally agree, though I don't think it could be 90's, from the style of the forks, the brake lever style and the very loopy brake cables. Those cables are an extra danger for people unused to them. You can easily get caught up in them.